# JavaScript clock / timer script on iOS not working

Tags: javascript, timer, http-post, clock

I have Timer javascript function which works well, but on iOS I can only see `aN:aN:aN` result. Here is the code:

```
 function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
      'total': t,
      'days': days,
      'hours': hours,
      'minutes': minutes,
      'seconds': seconds
    };
  }

  function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
    var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
    var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
    var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

    function updateClock() {
      var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

      hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
      minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
      secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);


      if (t.total <= 0) {
        $( "#end-of-translation" ).submit(); 
      }

        if($("#addtime_form").length == 0) {
          if(t.total <= 300000) {
            $("#addtime-form").append("<input id='addtime_form' type='submit' name='addtime' value='Add 15 minutes'>");
          }
        }
    }

    updateClock();
    var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
  }

  var now = Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((now / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((now / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var left_to_hour = 60 * 60 * 1000 - (minutes * 60 + seconds) * 1000;

  initializeClock("clockdiv", deadline);
```

Can someone tell me why I get NaN instead time?

My second problem is POST request on iOS. I can not find in POST array input type=submit param... so I need to change in the whole project if statements form:

```
 if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['submit']))
```

to only:

```
 if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Seems like you should be asking two separate questions since they are really not related.

Comment: So what is `deadline` ?

Comment: Ok but first question is the most important. deadline is predeclared variable to  get time when timer will have to stop.

Comment: I know what it is, but what is the exact value you store in the variable.... Are you positive it is a proper date format?

Comment: $deadline = strtotime("+".$stopIn." minutes", strtotime($timeReserved));
$deadline = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$deadline);

var deadline = <? echo $deadline; ?>

Comment: So what is echoed to the page.... I want the string, not the php

Comment: I printed deadline variable in alert and show: 2018-08-03 14:30:01 I added 15minutes to current time for reservation

Comment: function getTimeRemaining(endtime) returns NaN don't know why

Comment: Basically IOS does not like the format, the dupe link shows you how to alter it to make it work.